# Outlook returns error: The messaging interface has returned an unknown error

Tags: c#, outlook

I am having some problems with a piece of code, I am trying to import data from a source (at this time an access database) into a custom form but i keep getting the above error.

When i use a VBscript inside the source database all contacts import correctly.
When i repair the PST it still gives this error.
When i add a delay of 450 ms. the error also occurs but later on in the process.
Having Outlook opened or closed does not matter.

I am using the following method

```
string[] arrFolders = strFolders.Split('\\');

        Outlook.Application app = null;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = null;

        try {
            app = new Outlook.Application();
            folder = app.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders[arrFolders[0]];
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            writeLogLine("Error creating Outlook instance: " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Error creating Outlook instance\r\n" + ex.Message);
            intErrorCount++;
            blnHasErrors = true;
            blnAbort = true;
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 1; i < arrFolders.Length; i++) {
                folder = folder.Folders[arrFolders[i]];
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            writeLogLine("Error navigating to DRM folder: " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Error navigating to DRM folder\r\n" + ex.Message);
            intErrorCount++;
            blnHasErrors = true;
            blnAbort = true;
        }

        setProgressbarMaximum(dtResults.Rows.Count);
        setProgressbarMode(ProgressBarStyle.Continuous);

        //int intRowCount = 0;

        foreach (DataRow drItem in dtResults.Rows) {

            if (strDRMType == "Contact") {
                try {
                    Outlook.ContactItem x = (Outlook.ContactItem)folder.Items.Add("IPM.Contact." + strFormName);

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrMappings.GetLength(0); i++) {

                        if (arrMappings[i, 1] != null && drItem[arrMappings[i, 0]].ToString() != "") {
                            x.UserProperties[arrMappings[i, 1]].Value = drItem[arrMappings[i, 0]].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    x.Save();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    writeLogLine("Error importing contact: " + ex.Message);
                    intErrorCount++;
                    blnHasErrors = true;
                }
            }
```

as i said, when i loop the code it will throw exceptions after 100 to 200 contacts, when i add a delay it will get to contact 400/500 before failing.

This code is supposed to be for a generic import tool for this specific form so there is no need for hardcoding the source column names to the form fields in the import code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exceptions? how do you loop the contacts?

Comment: The exception is mostly empty except for the message which is "The messaging interface has returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook.". i'll edit the post to include the full code

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is not an Outlook add-in, since you say it doesn't matter if OL is open or closed, right?

One thing you may want to do is ensure you are releasing the COM objects once you are done with them, using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(...). Also, when you use dot notation like "namespace.Folders[..].Name" you are actually leaking a reference to both the Folders collection object and a Folder object.

When you do folders.Items.Add(...) inside a loop, that leaks a lot of objects.

So, clean up your COM references first, and see how that affects your situation.

Here's how I typically use COM objects:

```
MyComLib.Foo foo = null;
try
{
   foo = new MyComLib.Foo();
   foo.DoSomething();
} catch(COMException exc)
{
   // handle error, or rethrow
}
finally
{
   if(foo != null)
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(foo);
}
```

Comment: i tried `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(x)` after each `x.Save()` but i still got a lot of errors, do you mean i should re-open the folder everytime when i add an object?

Comment: I think you're still leaking a massive number of references. What's the purpose of this code?

            for (int i = 1; i < arrFolders.Length; i++) {
                folder = folder.Folders[arrFolders[i]];
            }

This effectively leaks 2 COM references per iteration. If there are 100 folders, you will leak 200 references - the folder object and folder.Folders (which is itself a COM reference).

Comment: Outlook.ContactItem x = (Outlook.ContactItem)folder.Items.Add("IPM.Contact." + strFormName);

This code leaks the Items property, so make sure you release that. Don't release folder.Items literally as that will just create a new reference and release it. Assign an Outlook.Folders variable to that property and use that reference. When done with it, release it.

    x.UserProperties[arrMappings[i, 1]].Value = drItem[arrMappings[i, 0]].ToString();

This code leaks the UserProperties object, so be sure to release that explicitly as well.

Comment: what i do is dynamically getting the folder from a string, as far as i know i cant do `folder = app.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders["root\\foo\\bar"];` and what i read in what you said is that i also should do `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(x.UserProperties)`